# Apache Pig Nulls and COGROUP Operators with multiple relations

Tags: operators, apache-pig

The below example is taken from Apache Document. My doubt is When using Nulls and COGROUP Operators with multiple relations, how we are getting null tuple in the output.

```
A = load 'student' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);

B = load 'student' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
dump B;
(joe,18,2.5)
(sam,,3.0)
(bob,,3.5)

X = cogroup A by age, B by age;

dump X;

(18,{(joe,18,2.5)},{(joe,18,2.5)})
(,{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)},{})
(,{},{(sam,,3.0),(bob,,3.5)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **COGROUP** will do **OUTER JOIN** between the two relation, that is the reason you are seeing null in the output.

If you do **INNER JOIN**, you will not get this null .

```
C = cogroup A by age INNER, B by age INNER;
```

This document will give more info about cogroup and Null.
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#cogroup